# Generate PDF using tcpdf from WordPress admin side custom page

Tags: wp-admin

I'm generating PDF using tcpdf library in WordPress admin side. but getting the following error.
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

It has header_sent() is true means it has set its headers already and not modifying the pdf headers by tcpdf. any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried putting your code in earlier during the load process? `admin_init` or earlier?

Comment: No, how I can do that ? I'm outputting the code at top of custom admin page.

Comment: put it in a function then attach that function to a hook

Comment: in this hook admin_init ?

Comment: I tried this <br />
**
function generate_pdf_test_with_admin(){
 echo 'test'; 

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'generate_pdf_test_with_admin' );**

<br />
but it doesn't echo anything on page

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this:

On the page where you are currently trying to output the PDF to the browser, save the PDF to a file on your server instead. Then, add a link to the file on your admin page.

This way the download of the PDF is a separate browser GET request and there will be no problem with headers.

If you are trying to output HTML and a PDF on the same admin page then it will never work, no matter how early in the page-render you put the PDF output.